# Offline modifications via subversion

Tags: svn

I've been developing a website (PHP+MySQL) for a while now, and for the last few months I've been working (with Coda) directly to the server, as the website was not officially online. Now we've reached a point where everything works more or less as expected, and basic functions are covered.

What I want to do now is set a copy of the website as it is right now in another hosting, so I can make changes and testing there, my client can check things out, and then, when we are completely sure that everything is working fine, move the files to the production server.

I guess my best choice is to take advantage of SVN, but I'm new to it and I don't know much about its workflow. Should I set up a repository + working copy on my Mac localy, with the remote server (development) mirrored so the client can check the changes; and then apply svn patches to the production server?

Also, there are a few files (config.php, initialize.php, .htaccess) which vary in a few lines depending on the server. Can I keep these changes out of the svn workflow so only real updates are registered?

Any help will be appreciated since I am feeling pretty lost on this...

PS: I use Versions as svn client, under OSX

Answer (score 0):

**Working copies method**

Both Staging&Prod sites are separate Working Copies of repo. You work in your workplace, commit to repo. For testing on Staging perform `svn up` on it, transfer on  Prod -  less frequent `svn up` too

**Build-system**

You have (two) scripts, which, on demand, do `svn export` + `rm -f <site root>` + `scp|ftp <exported dir>`

Problem of different configs *can be solved* by using 2 branches for 2 sites, 2 local Working Copies for you and 2 different sources for site-WCs or exports